# Regarding Database mail configuration in sql server web edition 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have enabled the database mail and sql agent service both and just to test whether  the database mail is working or not, i configured the database mail, created the profile and account along with all the required details like (server name, display name, port, ssl, basic authentication) however when i tried to send test email and i am getting error in the server logs that is "unable to send mail because of the mail server (failure sending email)" something like that. I have checked the server name thrice and it is absolutely correct. Please suggest what am i doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciaated.

**Note:- The same configuration i am using in enterprise edition and it is working perfectly fine.   I am able to get the test email.**

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? Have you compared all settings side-by-side with the working instance (SMTP username & password, port #, SSL etc)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply here. Please find the below error message which i can see in the server error logs:-   "Message
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2020-01-30T06:18:19). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (Failure sending mail.).
)"   And would also like to tell you that yes i have checked all the setting side by side, everything is same.

Comment: Can you send from the server where SQL is running using PowerShell (Send-MailMessage)? Its possible your SMTP server is blocking requests from unauthorised hosts, testing via PowerShell should indicate if this is occurring.

Comment: Could you please guide me the steps how can i send mail using powerShell?

Comment: You just need to call the [Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7) cmdlet and pass in the required info